# Prove/Disprove: if $v$ is a leaf in all MST's, it has same predecessor

Tags: graph-theory

I've faced a question and failed to disprove it yet, so I am starting to think it is actually a proof.

> Prove/disprove: It is given that in all MST's of a an undirected and weighted graph $G$, the vertex $v$ is a leaf. Then, in all such MST's, $v$ has the same predecessor (father).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False: Take the $3$-cycle on vertices $a,b,c$ with the weight of edges $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ equal to two, and the weight of edge $(b,c)$ equal to one. Then $v=a$ is the vertex that is a leaf on all/both MSTs, but it has different predecessors in each.

Answer (score 0):

**Disprove:**
Consider [Prim's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm):

1. Input: A non-empty connected weighted graph with vertices V and
   edges    E (the weights can be negative).
2. Initialize: Vnew = $\{x\}$, where $x$ is an arbitrary node (starting point)
   from $V$, $E_{new}$ = $\emptyset$.

   Repeat until $V_{new} = V$:

   2.1 Choose an edge $(u, v)$ with minimal weight such that $u$ is in $V_{new}$ and
   $v$ is not (if there are multiple edges with the same weight, any of
   them may be picked)

   2.2 Add v to Vnew, and $(u, v)$ to $E_{new}$
3. Output: $V_{new}$ and $E_{new}$ describe a minimal spanning tree

In step 2.1, we choose the edge which has the minimum weight.

Say that, $T = \{T_1, T_2, ...\}$ is the minimum spanning tree set of $G$.
For a vertex $v$, who is a leaf ın both $T_i$ and $T_j$, $v$ has the same parent in both if and only if all the edges $\forall(u,v) \in E$ have different wieights.

Comment: I don't see how any of the Prim's algorithm stuff is supposed to connect to the last paragraph, or where the assertion in the last sentence is justified.

Comment: @user2357112 Step 2.1, we choose a **minimal** edge among all. If there is one minimal edge, $v$ has the same parent. If there is more than one, $v$ might have more than one parents.

Comment: It's not making the choice out of the set of edges to $v$, though. It's choosing the minimal edge connecting the tree to any node not in the tree. You can have ambiguous decisions that lead to the same tree in all paths. It's possible to resolve this, but really, bringing in Prim's algorithm at all is just unnecessary complication.